# Multiple message processed

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I have a spring xd source module which pulls file from s3 and  splits line by line.I have my spring config as below.But I have 3 container and 1 admin server.Now I see duplicate message being processed by each container as each of them is downloading there own copy.
I can solve with making source s3 module deployment count as 1 but my processing of message is getting slow.?Any inputs to solve this?

```
   <int:poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" default="true">
    <int:advice-chain>
            <ref bean="pollAdvise"/>

            </int:advice-chain>
    </int:poller>


    <bean id="pollAdvise" 

    </bean>






    <bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">
        <property name="accessKey" value="#{encryptedDatum.decryptBase64Encoded('${accessKey}')}"/>
        <property name="secretKey" value="${secretKey}"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
        <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
        <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
    <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="s3Operations" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.core.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentials"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
        <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
        <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
        <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value="${awsSecurityKey}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="encryptedDatum" class="abc"/>

    <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  -->
    <int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                        bucket="${bucket}"
                                        s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                        credentials-ref="credentials"
                                        file-name-wildcard="${fileNameWildcard}"
                                        remote-directory="${remoteDirectory}"
                                        channel="splitChannel"
                                        local-directory="${localDirectory}"
                                        accept-sub-folders="false"
                                        delete-source-files="true"
                                        archive-bucket="${archiveBucket}"
                                        archive-directory="${archiveDirectory}">
    </int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>

  <int-file:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="output" markers="false" charset="UTF-8">

        <int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()"/>
            </bean>
        </int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>

</int-file:splitter>

    <int:channel id="output"/>
```

[Updated]
I added  the idempotency as suggested by you with a metadata store.But since my xd is running in 3 container cluster with rabbit will simple metadatastore work?I think I should use reds/mongo metadata source.If I use mongo/redis metadatastore  howcan i evict/remove the messages  because messages will pile up over time?

```
<int:idempotent-receiver id="expressionInterceptor" endpoint="output"
                              metadata-store="store"
                             discard-channel="nullChannel"
                             throw-exception-on-rejection="false"
                              key-expression="payload"/>

    <bean id="store" class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.SimpleMetadataStore"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to take a look to the [`Idempotent Receiver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver).

With that you can use shared [`MetadataStore`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metadata-store) and don't accept duplicate files.

The `<idempotent-receiver>` should be configured for that your `<int-file:splitter>`. And yes: with the discard logic to avoid duplicate message.

**UPDATE**

> .But since my xd is running in 3 container cluster with rabbit will simple metadatastore work?

That doesn't matter because you start the stream from the S3 `MessageSource`, so you should filter files already there. Therefore you need external shared `MetadataStore`.

> .If I use mongo/redis metadatastore howcan i evict/remove the messages because messages will pile up over time?

That's correct. It is a side affect of the Idempotent Receiver logic. Not sure how it is a problem for you if you use a DataBase...

You can clean the collection/keys by some periodic task. Maybe once a week...

Comment: Updated  questions with my implementation suggested by you. Please let me know your inputs..

Comment: "That doesn't matter because you start the stream from the S3 MessageSource, so you should filter files already there. Therefore you need external shared MetadataStore. "  In that case simplemetadata store won't work because its per instance? Can simple metadata store can be shared across instanced

Comment: ??? I don't know how the simple in-memory store can be shared across instances. Right, you can take a look to the Hazelcast `DistributedMap` for the `SimpleMetadataStore`, but you end up with the same pile up problem.

Comment: yes you are right I was bit confused we need some shared cache.Thanks for your insights!It helps