# duplicate message processed when polling files from s3

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I am using s3 module to poll files from s3.It downloads the file to local system and starts processing it.I am running this on 3 node cluster with module count as 1.Now lets assume  the file is downloaded to local system from s3 and xd is processing it.If xd node goes down it would have processed half the message.When  the server comes up it will start processing file again hence I will get duplicate message.I am trying to change to idempotent pattern with message store to change the module count to 3 but still this duplicate message issues will be there.

```
  <int:poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" default="true">
        <int:advice-chain>
                <ref bean="pollAdvise"/>

                </int:advice-chain>
        </int:poller>


        <bean id="pollAdvise" class="org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollSkipAdvice">
            <constructor-arg ref="healthCheckStrategy"/>

        </bean>

        <bean id="healthCheckStrategy" class="ServiceHealthCheckPollSkipStrategy">
                     <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
                      <property name="doHealthCheck" value="${doHealthCheck}"/>
         </bean>



        <bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">
            <property name="accessKey" value="${accessKey}"/>
            <property name="secretKey" value="${secretKey}"/>
        </bean>



        <bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
            <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
            <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
        <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/> 
        </bean>


        <bean id="s3Operations" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.core.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentials"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
            <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
            <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
            <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value=""/>
        </bean>



        <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  -->
        <int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                            bucket="${bucket}"
                                            s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                            credentials-ref="credentials"
                                            file-name-wildcard="${fileNameWildcard}"
                                            remote-directory="${remoteDirectory}"
                                            channel="splitChannel"
                                            local-directory="${localDirectory}"
                                            accept-sub-folders="false"
                                            delete-source-files="true"
                                            archive-bucket="${archiveBucket}"
                                            archive-directory="${archiveDirectory}">
        </int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>

      <int-file:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="output" markers="false" charset="UTF-8">

            <int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                    <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()"/>
                </bean>
            </int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>

    </int-file:splitter>

<int:idempotent-receiver id="expressionInterceptor" endpoint="output"
                              metadata-store="redisMessageStore"
                             discard-channel="nullChannel"
                             throw-exception-on-rejection="false"
                              key-expression="payload"/>

   <bean id="redisMessageStore" class="o.s.i.redis.store.RedisChannelMessageStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="redisConnectionFactory"
    class="o.s.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="port" value="7379" />
</bean>

        <int:channel id="output"/>
```

Update 2 
This configuration worked for me Thanks for your help.

```
<int:idempotent-receiver id="s3Interceptor" endpoint="s3splitter"
                             metadata-store="redisMessageStore"
                             discard-channel="nullChannel"
                             throw-exception-on-rejection="false"

                             key-expression="payload.name"/>

     <bean id="redisMessageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.redis.metadata.RedisMetadataStore">
        <constructor-arg ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redisConnectionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
        <property name="port" value="6379" />
    </bean>

    <int:bridge id="batchBridge"  input-channel="bridge" output-channel="output">

</int:bridge>


    <int:idempotent-receiver id="splitterInterceptor" endpoint="batchBridge"
                             metadata-store="redisMessageStore"
                             discard-channel="nullChannel"
                             throw-exception-on-rejection="false"

                             key-expression="payload"/>


    <int:channel id="output"/>
```

I had few doubts wanted to clarify If i am doing right.

1)As you can see I have ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice to delete the file.Will the file get deleted after i read the file into redis or after last record is read?

2)I explored redis using desktop manager I see this I have a MetaData as man Key[image]

Both (file and payload) metadatastore key and value are going to same table is this fine?or should it be different metadatastore?

Can i use hash of payload instead of payload as key?Is there something like payload.hash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is continuation of the [Multiple message processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903957/multiple-message-processed), but unfortunately we don't see `<idempotent-receiver>` configuration in your case.

According to your comment there looks like you continue to use `SimpleMetadataStore` or clean the shared one (Redis/Mongo) very often.

You should share more info where to dig. Some logs and DEBUG investigation would be good, too.

**UPDATE**

The Idempotent Receiver is exactly for `endpoint`. In your config it is for the `MessageChannel`. That's why you don't achieve any proper work, because the `MessageChannel` is just ignored from the `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor`.

you should add an `id` for your `<int-file:splitter>` and use that `id` from the `endpoint` attribute. Not should if that would be good idea to use `File` as a `key` for idempotency. The `name` sounds better.

**UPDATE 2**

> If a node goes down and lets assume a file is dowloaded(file size with million records may be gb) to xd node and I would have processed half the records and node crashes .When server comes up I think we will process same records again?

OK. I got your point finally! you have an issue with splitted lines from the file already.

Also I'd use Idempotent Receiver for the `<splitter>` as well to avoid duplicate files from S3.

To fix your use-case you should place in between `<splitter>` and `output` channel one more endpoint - `<bridge>` to skip duplicate lines with the Idempotent Receiver.

Comment: added my metadata store logic.Will this pattern avoid duplicate message due  server failure when server xd node goes down and again comes up .The file will be processed from beginning.

Comment: The channel isn't endpoint. You should use the id for the splitter. Will answer to you properly when reach the computer

Comment: Thanks will try that If i use hash of payload as idempotent key?The scenario is duplicate message processed.If a node goes down and lets assume a file is dowloaded(file size with million records may be gb) to xd node  and I would have processed half the records and node   crashes .When server comes up I think we will process same records   again?

Comment: See an UPDATE 2 in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help pls help me clarify few doubts.